# how to fix this error? I am using superset for react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, apache-superset

I am trying to integrate superset to my app but I can't since I face this error, which is related to frame while I don't use frame in my code, This is the code:

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { authSelector } from "../../../redux/slices/auth";
import { embedDashboard } from "@superset-ui/embedded-sdk";
import { useEffect } from "react";

function SupersetDashboard({ token }) {
  const { company } = useSelector(authSelector);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) return;
    embedDashboard({
      id: "49271a6d-182b-4761-9e6c-bf2c51bd1be2",
      supersetDomain: "https://dashboard.munjz.com/",
      mountPoint: document.getElementById("superset-iframe"),
      fetchGuestToken: () => token,
      dashboardUiConfig: {
        hideTitle: true,
        hideChartControls: true,
        hideTab: true,
      },
      rls: [{ clause: `company_id = ${company.id}` }],
    });
  }, []);

  return <div id="superset-iframe"></div>;
}

export default SupersetDashboard;
```

and this is the error:

```
Refused to display 'https://dashboard.munjz.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

This is for showing data in my webpage

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the site because server set to access from only same origin (domain). If you can administrate 'https://dashboard.munjz.com/', delete 'X-Frame-Option' header or add `ALLOW-FROM` value.

Comment: Does it relared with domain, I meant should I add extra words to domain to work? Because I did not fint similar sitting in website.

Comment: Not domain, the 'https://dashboard.munjz.com/' app has set up to block incoming request from another origins so thats why it gives this error. Take a look to X-Frame-Option and cors so you can have an idea for solving it. If you don't have permission to update  'https://dashboard.munjz.com/' you can not access this domain.